# Is it possible to create a DNS subdomain containing special characters?

Tags: http, dns, subdomain

Is it possible to create a DNS subdomain containing special characters?

For example, is *.example.com or $.example.com valid according to the RFC for DNS?

Comment: I don't think * or $ are allowed, but I do know that there is an RFC for internationalized domain names. I think [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5890) is it, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question boils down to "Yes, but no, but sometimes yes".

At the protocol level, DNS strings (including names) are encoded as length+data, so the data can be anything. So in that way `*` and `$` are perfectly fine.

The level above the protocol is the human-name level. On *that* level there are restrictions on what names you can use. Since the 80s, the main restriction boils down to letters, numbers and `-` (as long as it's not at the beginning or end of a label). So in that way `*` and `$` are forbidden (except that `*` as the entire content of a label has a special meaning).

On top of that, these days we have internationalized names. That's a way to encode any Unicode string into a form that conforms to the above rule. This, way we can have names that look like `räksmörgås.se` to humans while they internally look like `xn--rksmrgs-5wao1o.se`. That `xn--` at the start is a prefix that says that this is an encoded name. You still can't use `*` or `$` in your names, but you can probably find something else in Unicode that looks close enough and that you *can* use... which is a security problem of its own.

The specification for all this is spread out over far too many RFCs. If you're curious, start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) and follow many, many links from there.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), domain name label can consist of letter, digit or hyphen (and it must begin with letter and end with letter or digit), so `$` is not allowed. The exception that has special treatment is `*`, used for wildcards, and explained in more detail [in RFC 4592](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592)